# Catch AssertionError - NodeJS - While using only version in URL, without any endpoints

Tags: node.js, routes, restify

Am following this tutorial for creating an API: https://auth0.com/blog/developing-well-organized-apis-with-nodejs-joi-and-mongo/

Problem am facing is, if I access `http://localhost:5000/v1`, it gives an error like this:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: pathname (string) is required

But if I pass a name after that `v1`, like this: `http://localhost:5000/v1/abc` , it would give `Method not found` error(if the route is not found).

So, how can I catch this AssertionError and handle it ?

And my main code looks like this:

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
const config = require('./app/configs/configs')();
const restify = require('restify');
const versioning = require('restify-url-semver');
const joi = require('joi');

// Require DI
const serviceLocator = require('./app/configs/di');
const validator = require('./app/lib/validator');
const handler = require('./app/lib/error_handler');
const routes = require('./app/routes/routes');
const logger = serviceLocator.get('logger');
const server = restify.createServer({
  name: config.app.name,
  versions: ['1.0.0'],
  formatters: {
    'application/json': require('./app/lib/jsend')
  }
});

// Initialize the database
const Database = require('./app/configs/database');
new Database(config.mongo.port, config.mongo.host, config.mongo.name);

// Set API versioning and allow trailing slashes
server.pre(restify.pre.sanitizePath());
server.pre(versioning({ prefix: '/' }));

// Set request handling and parsing
server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(
  restify.plugins.bodyParser({
    mapParams: false
  })
);

// initialize validator for all requests
server.use(validator.paramValidation(logger, joi));

// Setup Error Event Handling
handler.register(server);

// Setup route Handling
routes.register(server, serviceLocator);

// start server
server.listen(config.app.port, () => {
  console.log(`${config.app.name} Server is running on port -
    ${config.app.port}`);
});
```

**/lib/error_handler.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports.register = (server) => {
    var httpStatusCodes = require('http-status');

    server.on('NotFound', (req, res) => {
        res.send(
            httpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND,
            new Error('Method not Implemented', 'METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED')
        );
    });

    server.on('VersionNotAllowed', (req, res) => {
        res.send(
            httpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND,
            new Error('Unsupported API version requested', 'INVALID_VERSION')
        );
    });

    server.on('InvalidVersion', (req, res) => {
        res.send(
            httpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND,
            new Error('Unsupported API version requested', 'INVALID_VERSION')
        );
    });

    server.on('MethodNotAllowed', (req, res) => {
        res.send(
            httpStatusCodes.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
            new Error('Method not Implemented', 'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED')
        );
    });

    server.on('restifyError', (req, res) => {
        res.send(httpStatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, err);
    });
};
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports.register = (server, serviceLocator) => {

  server.post(
    {
      path: '/users',
      name: 'Create User',
      version: '1.0.0',
      validation: {
        body: require('../validations/create_user')
      }
    },
    (req, res, next) =>
      serviceLocator.get('userController').create(req, res, next)
  );

  server.get(
    {
      path: '/users/:username',
      name: 'Get User',
      version: '1.0.0',
      validation: {
        params: require('../validations/get_birthdates-user.js')
      }
    },
    (req, res, next) =>
      serviceLocator.get('userController').get(req, res, next)
  );

  server.get(
    {
      path: '/birthdates/:username',
      name: 'Get Birthdates',
      version: '1.0.0',
      validation: {
        params: require('../validations/get_birthdates-user.js')
      }
    },
    (req, res, next) =>
      serviceLocator.get('birthdateController').listAll(req, res, next)
  );

  server.post(
    {
      path: '/birthdates/:username',
      name: 'Create Birthdate',
      version: '1.0.0',
      validation: {
        body: require('../validations/create_birthdates')
      }
    },
    (req, res, next) =>
      serviceLocator.get('birthdateController').create(req, res, next)
  );
};
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think the issue is with the `restify-url-semver` module

Comment: i think this is related to dependency requirement of restify-url-semver as in repo package.json the version of restify:4.3.1 and semver: 5.3.0 for more ref. https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1644

Answer (score 0):

just change the module `restify-url-semver` with `"restify-url-semver-parser": "^1.0.3"`
see the docs for implementaion no major change required [github-url](https://github.com/drodriques/restify-url-semver-parser) just replace two lines

- `const versioning = require('restify-url-semver');` with `const versioning = require('restify-url-semver-parser');`
- `server.pre(versioning({prefix: '/'}))` with `server.pre(versioning);`

use only if you want versioning in you prject